# AstroPy get sidereal time of current location

Tags: python-3.x, astronomy, astropy

I want to get the current sidereal time of my location using AstroPy, but the results are wrong. My code is as follows:

```
from astropy.coordinates import EarthLocation
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy import units as u

observing_location = EarthLocation(lat=46.57*u.deg, lon=7.65*u.deg)
observing_time = Time(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), scale='utc', location=observing_location)
LST = observing_time.sidereal_time('mean')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What results did you obtain, and what did you expect? (Also, PEP-8 asks that you name it `lst`, in lower case.)

Comment: This code gives correct results for me.

Comment: Works for me, substituting the actual telescope coordinates for mine. Are you sure you have the sign of the Longitude right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` to `datetime.now()`